# Rails / Carrierwave gem - How can I access the image upload data as JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, carrierwave

The Carrierwave gem allows me to enable users to upload one or more images (e.g., an avatar) and to display these images on a Rails-generated page, thus:

```
<%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url(:thumb)) %>
```

I'm wondering whether it's possible to retrieve the image data as JSON such that I receive a JSON response that looks like this:

```
[
    {
      "title": "The Title",
      "description": "The description",
      "url": "the/url",
      "thumbnail: "the/thumbnail/url"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a controller create a method (example :index)

```
def index
  @images = current_user.images.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @images }
  end
end
```

You would access by browsing to /images/index.json. In this example users are setup using Devise so you get the current_user method. This works if the user is logged into the site. To get it working without having to have the user login create a token.

This also assumes that there is a separate model for images that belongs to users.