# How can I produce json response with image url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, carrierwave

My question is same as the one posted two years before. But unfortunately no answer is found. So I am posting a link to that question.Can someone help me to solve the issue [Previous Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413458/rails-carrierwave-gem-how-can-i-access-the-image-upload-data-as-json). I have in User.rb

```
def as_json(options={})
   super(:only => [:id,:email,:provider,:full_name,image_url(:thumb), image_url])
end
```

But is not producing image url .I need absolute address for thumb and image url. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use ActiveModel::Serializers or jBuilder. While you can include the routes helpers in your models they should not really be doing JSON formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share how I solved the question. But I don't know its the proper way.
I have added

```
def as_json(options={})
    h = (:only => [:id,:email,:provider,:full_name)
    h[:image]   = imageurl
    h[:thumb] = thumb
    h
end

def imageurl
   ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url(self.image.url)
end

def thumb
  ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url(self.image_url(:thumb))
end
```

This code solved my issue